# Redirecting single page from other domain to main domain causes too many redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect only my `/login` page on another domain, to my main domain.

What I currently have, however, causes too many redirects.

What am I missing?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^login https://www.domain.com/login [R=301,L]  GIVES TOO MANY REDIRECTS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Is `/login/` a directory?

Comment: @anubhava Nope, no directory.

Comment: Uncomment `/login` rule and then open Firebug and visit `http://otherdomain.com/login` page to see how many redirects are happening

Comment: @anubhava About 21 redirects before Firefox cuts the infinite loop.

Comment: Ok but what are those redirects? Are they redirecting to `http://otherdomain.com/login` and `http://domain.com/login` back and forth?

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, they all redirect to `otherdomain.com/login` instead of `domain.com/login`

Comment: ok comment out all rules except login rule for testing and test in a new browser.

Comment: Is this some CMS framework in place?

Comment: @anubhava No CMS. When only using the `otherdomain.com/login` rule, it just stays on `otherdomain.com/login`

Comment: Hmm I don't understand requirement behind 1st and 3rd redirect rules. Other than `/login` do you want all URLs to how `https://domain.com/abc` OR `https://www.domain.com/abc`

Comment: @anubhava All URLs `http://www.domain-of-choice.com/abc`. `/login` to `https://www.domain.com/login`

Comment: You want `https://www.domain-of-choice.com/abc` instead of `http://` right?

Comment: @anubhava `https` ONLY for `domain.com`. But only really necessary for `/login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?otherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^login https://www.domain.com/login [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And make sure to test in a new browser to avoid browser's 301 caching.

Comment: Now every page redirects to `domain.com`. Only `/login` needs to be redirected.

Comment: Almost! On `otherdomain.com` there's no `www`-fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems.

A.

Your https redirection doesn't check if you're already using https. Therefore, after redirecting to `https://www.domain.com/login`, your `https` rule kicks in.

Normally, you would change your first rule by adding this condition (first line at the top):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it seems to me you can delete that rule altogether, since you are already forcing https with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Try that: uncomment the login rule, and comment out the first https rule.

B. The second problem is that otherdomain.com redirects to itself:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^login https://www.domain.com/login [R=301,L]  GIVES TOO MANY REDIRECTS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

One condition applies to only one rule. Right now, this is causing files on otherdomain to redirect to themselves.

At the moment you need to comment out this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Still get too many redirects. I tried both your solutions. Keeps redirecting to `otherdomain.com/login`

Comment: Added part B to the answer.  :)

Comment: When applying Part B, it simply stays on `otherdomain.com/login`